# Trigger html popup from js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my JS i"ve got an IF condition. I want to be able to make a pop-up appear in my html page. How can I make the below pop up appear in javascript?

```
<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="welcome_message"></a>
     <div class="popup">
          <h2>Welcome</h2>
          <p>blah blah...</p>
     <div>
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" value=""/>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
prompt('Welcome\nblah blah...\n\nName');
```

would make a dialog box appear that says:

```
page. com says:

Welcome
blah blah...

Name ___________
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N9q7R/)

`\n` Creates a new line, and `prompt` takes user input.

Comment: exactly... but how can I trigger this via my js file?

Comment: @AnnaZeed That's the code that goes in the JS file, do I not understand correctly?

Comment: Ok. 1). There is a custom welcome message in my HTML page. 2). There is an external JS file connected to this HTML page by the <script src="... tag.  3). I want to trigger the welcome message in the HTML page through the javascript file. How?

Comment: @AnnaZeed Can you be more clear on "trigger the welcome message"?  Is it hidden?

Comment: sorry... yes it's hidden. YOu'll get a better idea [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NathaliaZeed/6GXAA/)

Comment: @AnnaZeed It's not hidden in that link, but in that case you could `document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block'` if the style is `hidden` at first.

Comment: The popup shows if the "Log In" is clicked... but not from the javascript file.

Comment: @AnnaZeed So, like, `document.getElementById('welcome_message').innerHTML = 'Welcome'`?

Comment: @AnnaZeed I'm really confused and don't get what you're saying, but I think you're listening for an undefined variable to be 3.

Comment: I gfot it sorted... Thanks Wobbuffet. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (jQuery):

```
$(document).on('click', '#welcome_message:not(.active)', function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.popup').show();
    return false;
})
.on('click', '#welcome_message.active', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('.popup').hide();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks coder3. But I'm looking for a way to trigger the HTML popup <div class="popup"> via javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Use js plugin like bootstrap or modal pop up. These plugin will provide css and different functionality as well.
[Bootsrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

**Edited**

You can find demo at following link http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals
If still you are facing any problem please let me know.

Comment: It will be more helpful if you add any code related to it.